# is std::move() the same as using reset() and release() together?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, unique-ptr

I am implementing a BST and I want to check which of these lines is correct /more efficient to delete a node and link its parent to its child ?

```
//        ________[a]_______
//       /                  \
//     _[b]              __[c]_
//    /                /       \
//  [d]              [d]       [e]
```

1)

```
a->left = std::move(b->left);
```

2)

```
a->left.reset(b->left.release());
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Regarding the efficiency question, GCC and Clang both [output exactly the same code](https://godbolt.org/g/EfN7Pr) when using the default deleter.